# Transpose of two vectors

Tags: matrices

Given vectors $a,b\in\mathbb{R}^n$, is it true that $ab^\intercal=ba^\intercal$?  I have tried to decompose this matrix, but am having trouble with keeping track of the columns and rows.

Comment: Compare the column spaces of the two matrices. Those should be easy to figure out.

Comment: Did you try any numerical examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming $a,b\;$are interpreted as column vectors, the answer is "no", not necessarily.

Try almost any numerical example.

For example, let
$$
a=\begin{bmatrix}1\\1\end{bmatrix}
\;\;\text{and}\;\;
b=\begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix}
$$
On the other hand, if $a,b\;$are interpreted as row vectors, then the given expressions are both just dot products, so
$$ab^T = a\cdot b = b \cdot a = ba^T$$

Answer (score 0):

Assuming they are column vectors, they are transposes of each other.

$(ab^T)^T = (b^T)^T(a)^T = ba^T$

or, looking at the product element-wise,

$[ab^T]_{ij} = a_ib_j$ and $[ba^T]_{ij} = b_ia_j$

then in general $a_ib_j \neq b_ia_j$ for $i \neq j$.

Comment: @M.Winter I did the same thing!

Comment: True, but how does that show that they are or are not equal?